# View loading before pressing table cell in cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview

I'mtrying to load a view when user press a button in a `NSTableView` cell, but the view is loaded before pressing the button. Could anyone identify my mistake?

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    _homearray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Inbox",
                                           @"SentItems",
                                           @"Notifications",
                                           @"Search",
                                           @"Upgrade",
                                           @"Logout", nil];

    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [self.tableView selectRowIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] 
                byExtendingSelection:NO];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView
{
    return [_homearray count];
}

- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)rowIndex
{
    return [_homearray objectAtIndex:rowIndex%[_homearray count]];
}

- (void)tableViewSelectionDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    if(self.tableView.selectedRow==0)
    {
        self.second = [[secondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"secondViewController" bundle:nil];
        self.second.view.frame = CGRectMake(100, 200, 300, 250);

        [self.window.contentView addSubview:self.second.view];
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you `selectRowIndexes:byExtendingSelection:`?

Comment: @Cfr which line you saying

Comment: 6:`[self.tableView selectRowIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] byExtendingSelection:NO]`

Comment: leave that line it is unused one

Comment: whether that may causing the problem i think so in that line am just setting index to zero to load the data from that index point of value

Comment: Why is the app delegate also the tableview delegate?  That belongs in the `NSWindow` subclass.